# knative kafkasource consuming from earliest offset even though initialOffset configured to latest

Tags: knative

What could force the knative kafkasource to consume from earliest instead of latest when configured to do so?

We are using knative kafkasource and configured the initialOffset = latest.
Now we deleted the kafkasource consumer and kubernetes start to bring it up again. At the same time we also deleted the consumer group as well.
`kafka-consumer-groups.sh \ --bootstrap-server $KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_ENDPOINT \ --delete-offsets --group $EXAMPLE_CONSUMER_GROUP --topic $EXAMPLE_TOPIC`
so when the kafkasource pod came up, it then started consuming from the earliest offset instead of latest.
I tried checking this but did not find much in logs. I would like some help or pointer towards this   behavior of knative kafkasource and what could be possibly causing this? Or if anyone faced the same issue?
Thankyou!